# Printing to Powershell screen from within script function

Tags: powershell

Not sure what's going on.  I have a PS script file called `dothis.ps1` with the following code:

```
Function dothis($in) 
{
  Write-Host "Check $in"
}
```

Now, I call this in the regular powershell window (not ISE):

```
.\dothis.ps1 test
```

However, nothing is being printed to the screen.  What noob mistake am I making?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are forgetting to call the function:

```
Function dothis($in) 
{
  Write-Host "Check $in"
}

dothis          # Call function dothis
dothis 'hello'  # Call function dothis with an argument
```

Note too that PoweShell is not like a lot of programming languages which call functions like this:

```
# This is how languages such as C, Java, Python, etc. call functions
dothis()
dothis('hello')
```

For more information on PowerShell functions, see [here](http://windowsitpro.com/windows/create-your-own-powershell-functions).